# Docusign API call returns super() must be type, not str

Tags: python, jwt, docusignapi

I'm having an issue with JWT Oauth within the docusign API provided by swagger. I have a method that returns the JWT user token, but when I try and pass the access token to the DocusignAPI, via `self.api_client.get_jwt_token(access_token)` it returns an error `super() must be type, not str`. It seems like this error is generally an incorrect call of super() within the `__init__` method, however, the DocusignAPI seems to be set up correctly `class ApiClient(object):` with no super() called within the class. Any insight on why this would be or how to drill down to the main issue would be appreciated.

```
class DocusignObj(object):
    def __init__(self, prefs):
        self.api_client = docusign_esign.ApiClient()

    def get_token(self):
        # Call request_jwt_user_token method
        try:
            token_response = self.api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
                                        client_id=self.DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_ID,
                                        user_id=self.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID,
                                        oauth_host_name=self.DOCUSIGN_AUTH_SERVER,
                                        private_key_bytes=self.private_key,
                                        expires_in=28800,
                                        scopes=SCOPES)
        except ApiException as err:
            body = err.body.decode('utf8')
            if "consent_required" in body:
                consent_url = self.get_consent_url()
                webbrowser.open(consent_url)
                token_response = self.get_jwt_token()
        # access token returns is long string
        access_token = token_response.access_token
        # Save API account ID
        try:
            user_info = self.api_client.get_user_info(access_token)
        except TypeError as e:
            print(e)
            return
        accounts = user_info.get_accounts()
        api_account_id = accounts[0].account_id
        base_path = f'{accounts[0].base_uri}/restapi'
        self.json_token_info = {'access_token': access_token,
                                'api_account_id': api_account_id,
                                'base_path': base_path
                                }
        return self.json_token_info
```

Comment: The problem appears in the way the `super()` function is being called somewhere within the DocuSign API, specifically when you try to use the `get_jwt_token(access_token)`. Could you try to see a traceback to see where exactly?

Comment: Per my post super() is not called within the Docusign ApiClient class, so I'm not sure where that would be coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
api_client.set_default_header(
    header_name="Authorization",
    header_value=f"Bearer {access_token}"
)
```

To apply the `access_token` to your `api_client`

Comment: I have this called a bit later in the code. it works when I move it up to be in front of the ```ApiClient.get_user_info(access_token)```. However, since the ```get_user_info()``` does more than that, it still throws the same error.

Comment: looks like I needed to move some other code around. I followed your advice and moved this section of code, ```.set_base_path()```, and ```.set_oauth_hose_name``` before the ```get_user_info()``` and it appears to have worked. Thanks!